# FPDF - наложение строк

Tags: php, pdf

Идет наложение текста друг на друга, причем хаотично. Не понятно по каким причинам происходит наложение. Текст может состоять из трех строк, а может из десяти, но в результате всегда последняя строка находит на предыдущую.

Результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предоставлю неполный код, так как слишком длинный:

```
$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$fontName = 'Helvetica';
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);

// Дополнительная информация
$pdf->setFillColor(118, 203, 40);
$pdf->Rect(8, 195, 194, 9, 'F'); // F - заполнение, FD - заполнение и бордюр
$pdf->setFillColor(33, 159, 15);
$pdf->Rect(8, 195, 77, 9, 'F'); // F - заполнение, FD - заполнение и бордюр
$pdf->SetXY(10,199.5);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255);
$pdf->SetFontSize(14);
$pdf->Write(0, "Дополнительная информация");

$pdf->SetXY(10,210);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0);
$pdf->SetFontSize(12);

$pdf->Write(0, "Ограничение экскурсии: ");
$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, "Краткое описание экскурсии: " . strstr($goods_params["ks_description"], ".", true) . ".");
$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->Write(0, "Что нужно взять с собой: " . $goods_params["ks_with"]);

$filename = "check.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

Кто сталкивался с наложением текста в PDF, подскажите где найти решение?

Comment: Была у меня подобная проблема. Перешёл на другую библиотеку mpdf

Comment: @ArchDemon Ваш ответ помог решению, Вы бы ответили полноценно... Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

второй параметр в multicell отвечает за высоту элемента, нужно поставить значение повыше
$pdf->Write(0, **10**, "Что нужно взять с собой: " . $goods_params["ks_with"]);